# Immediate crash on device using SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags with iOS app

Tags: crash, reachability, ios4

I am using SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName & SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags to test for network availability in my iOS device.  When I run the app in the Simulator, or run it on the device, but attached to the debugger, everything's completely cool.  However, when I run the app on the test device but detached from the debugger, I get a crash. [EDIT: just realized I didn't indicate where: in the call to SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags]  The odd thing is, it doesn't happen the first time I run the check.  It happens on the second check.  And using a try/catch does absolutely nothing.

The crash is immediate.  There is no delay while the async polling occurs and the app just times out.  It's immediate.

This is completely effed.  I don't understand at all why this would be occurring.  I am getting ready to go to a conference to exhibit the app and its accompanying web app.  I was planning on walking the floor to show it off.  But now I'm basically restricted to keeping my iPhone/iPod tethered to my computer in the booth.

Any ideas?  Any work-arounds that don't keep me attached to the computer?  And any long-term solutions that solve this?  I use this method to check for network availability every time I perform any network activity.  I am syncing my data to the Cloud, and run this check each time a sync occurs.  I feel this is necessary to keep the user informed if there's a sudden break in the network connection.

Help????

Here's the code snippet.

```
+ (BOOL) networkConnected {
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
SCNetworkReachabilityRef netReachability;
BOOL retrievedFlags = NO;

BOOL reachable = NO;

netReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), [EXTERNAL_HOST UTF8String]);

@try {
    if(netReachability) {
        retrievedFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(netReachability, &flags);
        CFRelease(netReachability);
    }

    if(!retrievedFlags || !flags)
        reachable = NO;
    else
        reachable = YES;
} @catch (NSException *ex) {
    reachable = NO;
} @finally {
    return reachable;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing this kind of crash all of a sudden when using Hoptoad.

Comment: @chrispix - yes, I did.  Sorry for not following up.  I invoke it indirectly with: **[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(testNetworkLevel) toTarget:self withObject:nil];**  It's a threading issue.